# Pandas Boolean Indexing to Compare DataFrame and Results in List of Dicts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the below dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[70, np.nan, "hello"], [89, 3, 4], [210, 5, 64], [11, 75, 8]], columns=["ID", "A", "B"], dtype='object')

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[70, np.nan, "world"], [89, 33, 44], [21, 5, 6], [11, 7, 8]], columns=["ID","A", "B"], dtype='object')
```

df1 output below

```
    ID    A      B
0   70  NaN  hello
1   89    3      4
2   21    5     64
3   11   75      8
```

df2 output below

```
   ID    A      B
0  70  NaN  world
1  89   33     44
2  21    5      6
3  11    7      8
```

boolean mask highlighting differences

```
diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
```

Yielding:

```
      ID      A      B
0  False  False   True
1  False   True   True
2  False  False   True
3  False   True  False
```

How do I get a result that creates a list of dicts of the ID's and the true values for each row? I could set the id's as an index as well if needed.

final output would look like this

```
[{'ID': 70, 'B': 'world'}, {'ID': 89, 'A': 33, 'B': 44}, {'ID': 21, 'B': 6}, {'ID': 11, 'A': 7}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `where`, also I recommend output series not dict

```
s=df2.set_index('ID').where(diff_mask.drop('ID',1).values).stack()
Out[74]: 
ID   
70  B    world
89  A       33
    B       44
21  B        6
11  A        7
dtype: object
```

to dict

```
d=[y.unstack().reset_index().to_dict('r')[0] for x , y in s.groupby(level=0)]   
Out[111]: 
[{'ID': 11, 'A': 7},
 {'ID': 21, 'B': 6},
 {'ID': 70, 'B': 'world'},
 {'ID': 89, 'A': 33, 'B': 44}]
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. I actually need it in a dict, because I am sending it to an API that requires a dict format. Anyway to transform this into a dict?

Comment: I was stuck on this for quite some time. Very appreciative! This did the trick. :)